# Send Email to multiple recipients via the People Picker and sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I use infopath to design the forms and used a people picker.SharePoint Designer workflow sent mails to all the users selected in it picker. The mail only goes to the first recipient. How do i sent emails to multiple users using sharepoint designer workflow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check what type are you using in Designer workflow for People picker field? Is it string? Try selecting email or username delimited with semicolon(I exactly don't remember the attribute).

Even then if its not sending to all, log the people picker field value. Check if you are able to log all values or only the first value. This will give an idea as something is wrong in declaring the value.

Comment: I have updated the my Question with the screenshot of workflow and added the workflow variable placed in the to: section of the email action. Above example i tried email id. i even tried to copy the values of the people and group field to a text field but only the last entry is shown.But in the people and group picker field i can see all the users i have entred

Comment: something wrong with declaring the names. What if you directly refer the people field in Email address bar instead of Workflow variable? Try that

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing in my InfoPath form.. I have a people picker field in my InfoPath form.. I need my workflow to shoot e-mail to all the chosen ones in the people picker field.. How do I achieve it? Can show me step by step.. I'm very new to sharepoint and infopath.. please guide..

Comment: It will sent to the first entry and ignore all the other

Comment: Can you guide me the steps? If I'm able to do it I might find a solution to send to everyone

Comment: Dont Set vriable To with Togroup field values. Instead call Togroup field values directly in the To field of workflow email and then check

Comment: do you have skype or e-mail? I can show my form and workflow if you don't mind.. Your workflow is quite different then mine..

Comment: I did that Ankith only the first user id will be used for some reason and all the rest is ignored.

Comment: i havent figured it out myself Yuges

Comment: hi Yuges please see the link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1b12b5b-436c-4d3a-9d2e-3435ddd9dcb5/sharepoint-designer-send-email-to-multiple-users?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: ok...lets try other way around..create a simple workflow to just send email on item creation.. in To field call a SharePoint group or add multiple users. Check if now the mail is going. It should go.

After that in To field call a people picker field values with multiple names. Check if these all working.

Answer (score 0):

In the Return field text box make sure you use Display Names Semicolon delimited instead of Email Address

[image]